# Get multi-index value based on row number in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way to retrieve the multi-index value based on the row number?
Like can I use `.iloc[0]` to retrieve somehow the value of the multi-index in an array form?

For example I have a multi-index [month, day, hour]. Can I use iloc[numRow] and get for example (1,1,1) being the multi-index values month 1, day 1 and hour 1?

`df.iloc[numRow].get_index()` does not work since it becomes a series and then it returns the column names as the index, but I really want the value of the multi-index of the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
df.index[numRow]
```

(You can always use integer-based slicing on `Index` objects...)

Comment: OMG...I feel so stupid now...thanks for the answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Glad it helped. I remember having this particular epiphany. Useful stuff!  One other note: the to_series method (called on an index or multiindex object) is also quite useful. So while df.index.apply blows chunks, df.index.to_series().apply works nicely, etc.